# C# Compare Constructor Signature

Tags: c#, generics, constructor, func

How do you compare a constructor method?
Let say i have a class which has 3 constructor.

```
public class MyClass
{
        private string myName;
        private string mySurname;
        public MyName {get;set;}
        public MySurname{get;set;}    
        public MyClass()
        {}
        public MyClass(string myName)
        {
           this.myName = myName;
        } 
}
```

I have the below function that i used and i want to figure out which constructor is called.

```
public <T> GetBOData<T>(Func<T> Constructor) where T: Class
{
     if(Constructor signature already exist)
     {
        pull Cache value
     }
     ELSE
     {
       Invoke it and save the values into the cache.
     } 
}
```

The idea is if i already called this constructor somewhere in the app, add this into a DICTIONARY.
So if i call the same constructor again, it doesn't hit the database anymore. It just pulls the DICTIONARY value.

Currently using the MethodInfo as an identifier, but i realise it changes every winform therefore all my calls always hit the database.

Advance Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you want an IoC framework, [StructureMap](http://docs.structuremap.net/) for example

Comment: @Johan, Thanks for the input, i was looking for a more simple solution. I could just add a GUID for everytime a Constructor is called.

Comment: There is a chance that using an IoC framework is easier than writing one

Comment: Where is the dictionary stored?

Comment: @Yohannes: It's in a Main MDI Form which is static. Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us why you want:"The idea is if i already called this constructor somewhere in the app, add this into a DICTIONARY. So if i call the same constructor again, it doesn't hit the database anymore. It just pulls the DICTIONARY value."? We might be able to give you alternative.

Comment: HI @Macr, Just want to Cache a class base on a Constructor called.